# I have a button that changes the text in it when clicked but won't change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button on my page that starts an animation and it also stops it. On top of that, when you click the button, the text inside the button changes. So, when you click the button it starts the animation and changes the text but when you click it again it stops the animation and doesn't change the text back. I was wondering how I would do this. This is my code:
http://pastebin.com/aB83eKxL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the code to change the text back?  I didn't see it in your example.  You need to do something like:

```
    $('input#lightswitch').on('change', function() {
      if($('#ls').html() != 'RAINBOW!') $('#ls').html('RAINBOW!');
      else $('#ls').html('Normal button text');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single-line ternary expression.

Replace:
`$('#ls').html('RAINBOW!')`

With:
`$('#ls').html(($('#ls').html() == 'Rainbow Switch' ? 'RAINBOW!' : 'Rainbow Switch'))`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
  $(function() {
    var initialText = 'RAINBOW!';
    $('input#lightswitch').on('change', function() {
      var nextText =  $('#ls').html();
      $('#ls').html(initialText);
      initialText = nextText;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has too much code to go through it all (you should really post a simpler example for stuff like this) but this is one way to do what you need:

```js
$('#testbtn').click(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    if($this.val()=='Click Me') $this.val('Click Me Again')
    else $this.val('Click Me')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="testbtn">
```